# usage of __init__.py

Tags: python

I use `__init__.py` to run checks when I do `from myprojects.something import blabla`.

Today I started using `pyzmq` and I wanted to see what's going on behind the scenes. So I browsed the code in github and I find (for me) some strange usage of `__init__.py` there that I cannot explain myself.

For example [`zmq/core/__init__.py`](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/zmq/core/__init__.py). What's the point of adding in `zmq.core.__all__` the `__all__`'s value of `zmq.core.constants, zmq.core.error, zmq.core.message, etc.`?

In [`zmq/__init__.py`](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/zmq/__init__.py) I see at the end

```
__all__ = ['get_includes'] + core.__all__
```

where `get_includes` is a function which basically returns a list with the directory of the module and the utils directory in the parent directory.

What's the point of that? What has `__init.py__` achieved by doing that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `__all__` is for when someone does `from module import *` as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__all__#importing-from-a-package).

> The only solution is for the package author to provide an explicit
>   index of the package. The import statement uses the following
>   convention: if a package’s `__init__.py` code defines a list named
>   `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when from package import * is encountered. It is up to the
>   package author to keep this list up-to-date when a new version of the
>   package is released. Package authors may also decide not to support
>   it, if they don’t see a use for importing * from their package. For
>   example, the file `sounds/effects/__init__.py` could contain the
>   following code:

```
__all__ = ["echo", "surround", "reverse"]
```

> This would mean that `from sound.effects import *` would import the
>   three named submodules of the sound package.

One use for `__all__` is a tool for package builders to allow them to structure their package in a way that works for them while making it convenient for users.  Specifically in the case of pyzmq, it lets you write code such as:

```
import zmq
print zmq.zmq_version()
```

Rather than having to use the full dotted module name:

```
print zmq.core.version.zmq_version()
```

The package designers of pyzmq are using `__all__` to promote namespace elements from nested modules up to the top level of their namespace so the user isn't bothered by the structure of their package.

Comment: I've read this part of the documentation before asking here. But this still does not answer my question. Perhaps I should ask in another way: I though that the reason for using `from bla import ble` was that you had controll over your namespace, meaning that you decide which symbols you add to your namesapce.

Comment: As in contrast of C where using `#include` might cause collision with already defined functions, variables etc. you should only import the symbols you really need. I though I read somewhere in the python documentation that using `from bla import *` was not a good habit. If so, then why bother defining `__    all__` at all? And how does `__all__ = ['get_includes'] + core.__all__` get evaluated when doing a `import *`?

Comment: from bla import * is not a good habit to be in, but there are some modules for which that is generally safe. I routinely do from math import *. The documentation of those modules often points out that they are designed to be used that way and they support niceties like __all__ to make it a bit easier. But from x import * is stil something to be used with caution and only with packages where you know it won't cause a problem.

Comment: @John Gaines Jr: your last edit make a lot of sense. I asked myself why I was able to use `zmq.REQ` even though `REQ` is defined in `core.constants`. Thanks for sharing that.